# How to print unicode strings in a Python 2 shell under Windows?

Tags: python, windows-10, python-2.x, python-idle, unicode-string

I'm having problems when trying to print symbols such as €, ≤, Å, Ω, ℃, etc., in **Python 2.7.11** under **Windows 10**. I expected that running this piece of code from **IDLE**:

```
print u'\u20AC\u2A7D\u212B\u2126\u2103'
```

would produce the following output on the screen:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
€⩽ÅΩ℃
>>>
```

But it didn't. I obtained a funky string of non-ascii characters instead. After struggling for a while, I finally got the expected output by setting up an environment variable:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

So far, so good. My problem is that I am unable to get the same output from the **Python shell**:

```
>>> print u'\u20AC\u2A7D\u212B\u2126\u2103'
Ôé¼Ô®¢Ôä½ÔäªÔäâ
>>>
```

I have unsuccessfully tried a number of workarounds I found in answers to similar questions:

1. Changed the code page from 850 (which is the default in my system) to **65001** (which corresponds to utf-8 enconding)
2. Wrapped **sys.stdout** to ensure the appropriate encoding

   ```
   sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
   ```
3. Even changed - although it is widely discouraged - the **default encoding**

   ```
   sys.setdefaultencoding("UTF-8")
   ```

None of the above worked for me.

My question is twofold:

- **Why** if I run `print u'\u20AC\u2A7D\u212B\u2126\u2103'` from IDLE the output is `€⩽ÅΩ℃` (as expected) whereas if I run this code from the Python shell the output is incorrect?
- Does anyone have any **tips** for printing those symbols correctly from the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why: IDLE uses tkinter, which wraps the tcl/tk GUI framework.  Tcl/tk uses unicode strings, like Python 3, except that it is limited to the first 2**16 characters (the Basic Multilingual Plane, BMP).  On Windows, Python uses Command Prompt, which uses code pages mostly limited to 256 chars.  CP65001 seems to be a fraud; join the large crowd of people who have failed to get it to work over the last decade.  (Search web for `code page 65001`.)

Tip: unless you limit output to chars in a working codepage, use IDLE to run the program.  IDLE has a `-r file` startup option.  See Help => IDLE Help, 3.1 Command line usage.  I don't normally recommend using IDLE to run already developed programs, but do on Windows for BMP output.